# get_post title wordpress show comment box

Tags: wordpress, codex

I use this code for show all titles by catgory id use inside a shortcode function.

```
global $post;
$args = array( 'category' => 8);
$myposts = get_posts( $args );

foreach( $myposts as $post ){
    $post_title=$post_title."<br>".$post->post_title;   
}

$post_data.=$post_title;
echo $post_data;
```

The problem is that this code displays the comments of the last post and the comment box.

The problem is generated by the foreach, I remove the foreach and working properly.

I do not know how I can do to prevent this happen.

When I use only this code works fine, but i need all the titles.

```
$title_id= get_the_title( 214 );
```

On page I just put [name_shortcode]

Answer (score 0):

You are appending new value in `$post_data` but that is outside the loop. You should put it inside the loop to append all values.

```
$post_data ='';
foreach( $myposts as $post ){
  $post_title=$post_title."<br>".$post->post_title;   
  $post_data.=$post_title;
}
```